# JFrame repack after validate

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I am having a Class A extending JFrame and is the main class. Also i am having Class B extending JPanel. Whenever a button is pressed in the A frame then a new object of Class B is created and added to the A frame. Now, there is button in Panel B which when pressed the object is removed from the frame.

The problem over here is if i am continuously adding and removing the objects at some point of time the object is removed properly but the frame is not packed to the small size were it should go. Can someone please help me over here.

Edited 1 : So, while transporting my application code to the below generalized code i found that because i had written this.setResizable(false); hence randomly at some times the frame was not getting packed properly after removing the object. As soon as i commented out and tested it for some add/remove now it is woring fine. SetResizable is for the user to dont allow them to resize why it would be affecting the functionality over here any idea?

**Edited 2 : Tried to remove extra things from code.**

So, basically below is the question.

1. Create Panel1 in frame whose layout is gridbaglayout.
2. Add one button in the Panel1 when that is pressed create a new object of Class B and add into Panel1.
3. The Class B contains a button on press of that button Class B tells Class A to remove that object.
4. Class A removes the object and calls pack of frame.

Issue :

Over here, if we play around i.e. continuously add and remove the object B, there comes a time where the frame is not properly packed.

Observation :
So, the problem i found out was the setresizable if it is made to false then only this happens else it works fine.

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class A extends JFrame{

    private static A frame; 
    JButton AddNewButton;   
    static JPanel thePanel; 
    static int buttonBYPos = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new A();
    }

    A()
    {
        this.setTitle("Testing");

        this.setResizable(false);   
        frame = this;

        /* Make a panel to add buttons to it and set gridbaglayout to it*/
        thePanel = new JPanel();
        thePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        /* Make a new button and add it to the thePanel */
        AddNewButton = new JButton("Add New Button");
        ListenForButton lbutton = new ListenForButton();
        AddNewButton.addActionListener(lbutton);    
        addComp(thePanel,AddNewButton,0,0,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.BOTH);

        /* Add thePanel to frame and also set Frame parameters*/
        this.add(thePanel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);;
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getSource() == AddNewButton)
            {
                B b = new B();
                addComp(thePanel,b,0,buttonBYPos,1,1,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,GridBagConstraints.BOTH);
                buttonBYPos++;
                thePanel.revalidate();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }

    }

    private void addComp(JPanel thePanel, JComponent comp, int xPos, int yPos, int compWidth, int compHeight, int place, int stretch){
        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = xPos;
        gridConstraints.gridy = yPos;
        gridConstraints.gridwidth = compWidth;
        gridConstraints.gridheight = compHeight;
        gridConstraints.weightx = 100;
        gridConstraints.weighty = 100;
        gridConstraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gridConstraints.anchor = place;
        gridConstraints.fill = stretch;
        thePanel.add(comp, gridConstraints);
    }

    public static void removeBObject(B pointer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        buttonBYPos--;
        thePanel.remove(pointer);
        thePanel.revalidate();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}

class B extends JPanel
{
    JButton removeobj;  

    private B currentBObject;
    B()
    {       
        currentBObject = this;      

        removeobj = new JButton("Remove Object");
        ListenForButton lbutton = new ListenForButton();
        removeobj.addActionListener(lbutton);

        this.add(removeobj);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }   
    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == removeobj)
            {
                 A.removeBObject(currentBObject);           
            }

        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Post [mcve]. [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Try to `revalidate()` or place the validation logic in the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: @c0der updated the code section with working code. Also added extra observation on the setresizable part.

Comment: You can simplify your code by using borderLayout - north for "add" button and center for jpanel with box layout for Y axis - then you can simply add new panels to jpanel with box layout that will keep them in one row.

Comment: Do not post so much code. Post a [MCVE] : post the bare **Minimum** to show your issue. 
(As you see, writing a minimal case is a good debugging technique)

Comment: @c0der tried to edit and be clear on the question.

Comment: @StanislavOrlov i want to use gridbaglayout only as it is easy for the bigger application which i am developing.

Comment: Yes. It is more of a [MCVE] now